# It's regarding AWS Cognito email customization?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

In Cognito I have created the user name with an unique id for example (dbdhdydhdhhdh) and I am putting my email address to get the temp password to log in my UI ? 
But when I receive an email it's shows my unique id instead of name. So I trigger the lambda function to get my name in the email .My lambda is working fine and it's shows my user name when I get the password but along with the username the unique id is also reflecting.

Any suggestion how can I hide that unique id please ?

Answer (score 0):

Aws Cognito has lambda triggers may be you can customize your email content in that lambda trigger.

Please find the link [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, If I understood it correctly you want to send a custom email with other attributes (given_name, family_name etc), it is possible with Lambda triggers.
Have a look at this link - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html

Your user attributes should be coming inside

> event.request.userAttributes

and you should be able to use them in your email message.